# Can I send multiple files from multiple input form fields into a json array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax, html

I want to upload multiple files from different input fields from a form and pass it to json array and send it to server.

Comment: what you have tried..... and where is your code??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to show us what you've tried so far so that we can help you fix your code; We won't write the code for you. Also, please try to explain your problem as clearly as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using form data u can send it you have posted any code.
It uses jquery to create data which u can send with you ajax request. Please try below code

```
var ajaxData = new FormData();
ajaxData.append( 'action','uploadImages');
$.each($("input[type=file]"), function(i, obj) {
        $.each(obj.files,function(j, file){
            ajaxData.append('photo['+j+']', file);
        })
});
```